# Passing environmental variables as parameters

Tags: python, parameters

I need to pass few environmental variables as parameters that can do some job.

Example: In Perl, it would be something like this

```
my $g_folder = $ENV{'g_folder'};
my $assembly_name = $ENV{'genome_assembly_name'};

my $genome_seq = $g_folder . '/' . $assembly_name .".fa";
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Python. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `os.environ` ? I guess ?

Comment: You want to read an environment variable or pass on in to the program?

Comment: What are you actually doing?

Comment: From a galaxy like environment, I have few environmental variables passed eg g_folder and assembly. I need these parameters in my plugin .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

env_name = 'g_folder'
assembly_name = 'genome_assembly_name'

g = os.getenv(env_name)
assembly = os.getenv(assembly_name)

file_name = os.path.join(g, assembly) + ".fa"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would translate this to Python as:

```py
import os

g_folder = os.environ['g_folder']
assembly_name = os.environ['genome_assembly_name']
genome_seq = os.path.join(g_folder, assembly_name + '.fa')
```

Comment: Thanks. I did think of this first but this did not work. I tried the os.environ.copy to call the parameters to my subprocess but that didnt pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

here's the link to the os.environ module that should accomplish what you are looking for. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("some.exe.bin {genome_assembly_name}".format(**os.environ)
```

is yet another way of doing this ...